# How can I see if a Linux Embedded system authenticates with PAM or passwd only?

Tags: embedded, pam, ldap, petalinux

I cross compiled Linux-PAM and OpenLDAP for my linux embedded system (with ARM architecture) and copied the compiled files and folders into it. I create a /etc/pam.d/ folder and i put inside of it the files common-auth, common-password and common-account.
How can i make sure it authenticates with PAM?
For example from the command line when I digit:

```
su user1
```

how can I make sure the system authenticate only with passwd or with PAM?

This are the files I put inside the /etc/pam.d folder:

common-account:

```
account sufficient    /usr/lib/security/pam_ldap.so
account required    /lib/security/pam_unix.so try_first_pass
```

common-auth:

```
auth sufficient        /usr/lib/security/pam_ldap.so
auth required        /lib/security/pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
```

common-password:

```
password sufficient    /usr/lib/security/pam_ldap.so
password required    /lib/security/pam_unix.so nullok obscure min=4 max=8 md5 try_first_pass
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using

```
auth sufficient        /usr/lib/security/pam_ldap.so
auth required        /lib/security/pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
```

the module *pam_ldap.so* is tried first and authc will succeed if it returns `PAM_SUCCESS`. If not *pam_unix.so* will be tried next and login will fail if it does not return `PAM_SUCCESS`.

You can define more complex setups with the various PAM modules available. Please examine the PAM docs very carefully for not punching security holes in your setup.